# select2.js - How to align two items inside option element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want to align two items inside the `<option>` element using select2.js plugin.

For example, here:

```
<select id="myExample" class="pull-left">
    <option value="1" class="pull-left"><span class="pull-left">Item A </span><span class="pull-right">Company A</span></option>
</select>
```

I want Item A to be aligned on the left and Company A to be aligned on the right.

How can I achieve that? I tried using css only but it doesn't seem to be working.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/wphqwvLf/53/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a delimiter for your string, on my example I used "**~**" and then split this after select2 escaped your markup :

```
$("select").select2({
  escapeMarkup : function(text){
      text = text.split("~");
      return '<span class="pull-left">'+text[0]+'</span><span class="pull-right">'+text[1]+'</span>';
  }
});
```

While on your select, you should use something like :

```
<select id="myExample" class="pull-left">
    <option value="1" class="pull-left">
        Item A~Company A
    </option>
</select>
```

Here is a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wphqwvLf/55/

Comment: Thanks @Burimi. Any idea on how to show the dropdown? Looks like it's being cutoff.

Comment: I have made a slight adjustment here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pue3eba4/) adding a <br/>.

Comment: Thank you @DanEtchy How can I get rid of the "undefined" text when I use the search input?

Comment: This should solve your undefined problem... [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pue3eba4/3/) @brunodd

Comment: Super! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually writing the options yourself or are you getting them via ajax? Because I think that you wrote them yourself is the problem here. If you retrieve data via ajax you can use a formating function and it works fine.
Example:

```
function formatAdresses (email) {
    var $email = $("<span>"email.NACHNAME + "</span><span class='pull-right'>" + email.EMAIL + "</span>");
    return $email;
};
```

Comment: I am using static text for the example.